# Splitting a dataframe into several dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I need split into several dataframes, based on regex searches. There is no set pattern to the searches, i.e. sometimes there is a single regex, sometime a combination of several. Here is a minimal example with just one set of rows extracted:

```
Name <- c("John", "Jane", "Arthur", "Maggie")
Age <- c(20, 30, 31, 33)
City <- c("London", "Paris", "New York", "Delhi")

main_df <- data.frame(Name, Age, City)

sub_df <- main_df %>% 
  filter(grepl("J", Name))

main_df <- main_df %>% 
  filter(!grepl("J", Name))
```

Note that I am extracting some rows into a new dataframe, then deleting the extracted rows from the main dataframe.

I am looking for a single line command to do this. Help appreciated, especially if using `dplyr`.

Comment: For your example, this works : `split(main_df, grepl("J", main_df$Name))`

Comment: how about writing a function?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks. Split does the same as I am doing, but I am looking for the extracted lines to be deleted from main_df at the same time.

Comment: @Kaveh1000 if you do `new_df <- split(main_df, grepl("J", main_df$Name))`, `new_df[[1]]` and `new_df[[2]]` are your two new dataframes with other rows deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much @RonakShah for the explanation. So I am getting a list from the dataframe. What I am looking for is a that new_df is a dataframe with 2 rows, and main_df is now a dataframe with 2 rows, i.e. 2 rows are deleted. I think a function might be the answer.

Comment: What about `list2env(split(main_df, grepl("J", main_df$Name)), envir = .GlobaleEnv)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a function like

```
split_df <- function(df, char) {
  split(df, grepl(char, df$Name))
}

new_df <- split_df(main_df, "J")

new_df[[1]]
#    Name Age     City
#3 Arthur  31 New York
#4 Maggie  33    Delhi

new_df[[2]]
#  Name Age   City
#1 John  20 London
#2 Jane  30  Paris
```

In place of `char` make sure to pass appropriate character to split on. You can also use regex for `char` like `^J` (starts with J) or `J$` (ends with J) etc.

For example,

```
new_df <- split_df(main_df, "^J")
```

would give same output as above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will allow you to extract rows based on multiple conditions from the original `df` and delete them from the original, using `dplyr` as requested.

```
Name <- c("John", "Jane", "Arthur", "Maggie")
Age <- c(20, 30, 31, 33)
City <- c("London", "Paris", "New York", "Delhi")
main_df <- data.frame(Name, Age, City, stringsAsFactors = F)
conditions <- c(grepl("J",main_df$Name)) # works with several conditions as well
extractanddelete <- function(x, conditions) {
  condf <- data.frame(conditions)
  #fullcondition <- sapply(conditions, all)
  newdfs.list <- lapply(1:ncol(condf), function(i) x %>% filter(condf[,i]))
  newmain <<- x
  notcondf <- !condf
  sapply(1:ncol(condf), function(i) newmain <<- newmain %>% filter(notcondf[,i]))
  return(newdfs.list)
}
ndflist <- extractanddelete(main_df, conditions)
newmain
ndflist
> newmain
    Name Age     City
1 Arthur  31 New York
2 Maggie  33    Delhi
> ndflist
[[1]]
  Name Age   City
1 John  20 London
2 Jane  30  Paris
```

You receive a `list` containing as many elements as the conditions you use for filtering and deleting.

For completeness, you can then do `main_df <- newmain`

This solution also works for other conditions than just `grepl`

Answer (score 1):

I achieve it with `mapply()` function which apply function `assign()` to multiple list(vector) arguments.

**Note:** `pos = 1` is necessary

```
mapply(FUN = assign, x = c("main_df", "sub_df"),
                     value = split(main_df, grepl("J", main_df$Name)),
                     pos = 1)

main_df

#     Name Age     City
# 3 Arthur  31 New York
# 4 Maggie  33    Delhi

sub_df

#   Name Age   City
# 1 John  20 London
# 2 Jane  30  Paris
```