# Converting a list into a set of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966048/splitting-a-dataframe-into-several-dataframes#52966676). I am putting a follow-up here as it might be useful as a standalone question. I have the following minimal example `R` code:

```
Name <- c("John", "Jane", "Arthur", "Maggie","Harry", "Will")
Age <- c(20, 30, 31, 33, 30, 20)
City <- c("London", "Paris", "New York", "Delhi", "London", "Paris")

main_df <- data.frame(Name, Age, City)

split_df <- split(main_df, City)
```

In the real data I need to do a lot of complex `regex` manipulation of the text in one column, but that manipulation varies according to the element of the list produced by the `split()` function. So in this example, the same `regex` operations are needed for all elements in each `City`.

I am familiar with data frames, so my question is how can I convert each element of the list into a data frame to manipulate individually, then combine again. Preferably each data frame named with the category used to split, e.g. `City` in my example.

Any other ideas welcome. I note that splitting into individual data frames is not generally recommended!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Each element in `split_df` is already a data.frame. See `class(split_df[[1]])` and you can extract them with names as well `class(split_df$London)`. What exactly do you need to do differently?

Comment: What do you see when you look at `split_df[[1]]`? What is `class(split_df[[1]])`?

Comment: Looks like I have been missing something fundamental, in that each element of the list is actually a data frame. :-( Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

## Each of your list elements are already a `data.frame`:

```
> lapply(split_df, class)
$Delhi
[1] "data.frame"

$London
[1] "data.frame"

$`New York`
[1] "data.frame"

$Paris
[1] "data.frame"
```

---

## Use `lapply()` to apply functions to subsets of `data.frame`s by a condition

Here's a silly function that adds a new column named based on the city name:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  if(as.character(unique(x$City)) == "Paris"){
    x$woo = "yay"
  }
  if(as.character(unique(x$City))  == "New York"){
    x$woo = "woo"
  }
  if(as.character(unique(x$City))  == "London"){
    x$woo = "yippee"
  }
  if(as.character(unique(x$City))  == "Delhi"){
    x$woo = "alrightttt"
  }

  return(x)
}

> split_df <- lapply(split_df, my_fun)
> split_df
$Delhi
    Name Age  City        woo
4 Maggie  33 Delhi alrightttt

$London
   Name Age   City    woo
1  John  20 London yippee
5 Harry  30 London yippee

$`New York`
    Name Age     City woo
3 Arthur  31 New York woo

$Paris
  Name Age  City woo
2 Jane  30 Paris yay
6 Will  20 Paris yay


> split_df <- lapply(split_df, function(x){x$yay = "yay"; return(x)})
> split_df

$Delhi
    Name Age  City yay
4 Maggie  33 Delhi yay

$London
   Name Age   City yay
1  John  20 London yay
5 Harry  30 London yay

$`New York`
    Name Age     City yay
3 Arthur  31 New York yay

$Paris
  Name Age  City yay
2 Jane  30 Paris yay
6 Will  20 Paris yay
```

---

## Use `do.call()` and `rbind.data.frame()` to bind your list of `data.frame`s into one `data.frame`

```
> do.call(rbind.data.frame, split_df)
           Name Age     City        woo
Delhi    Maggie  33    Delhi alrightttt
London.1   John  20   London     yippee
London.5  Harry  30   London     yippee
New York Arthur  31 New York        woo
Paris.2    Jane  30    Paris        yay
Paris.6    Will  20    Paris        yay
```